# How to show all messages between current user and another user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm getting better at using clauses in Rails but I am running into a problem. I have the follow model setup:

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :recipient, class_name: 'User'
end

class CreateMessages < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :messages do |t|
      t.integer :user_id
      t.integer :recipient_id

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

In my controller I'm trying to show a list of messages where the `user_id` is either the `current_user` or the `@message.recipient` or the `recipient_id` is the `current user` or the `@message.recipient`. Which basically means, I want to show messages between the current user and another user whether the current user sent it or received it.

```
  def show
    @message = Message.find(params[:id])
    @messages = Message.all.where('user_id IN (?) AND recipient_id IN (?)', @message.recipient_id, @message.recipient_id)
  end
```

But the above doesn't work or using `OR` in the statement. I can't really think this out in my head so how would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SQL searches

`@messages = Message.all.where('user_id IN (?) AND recipient_id IN (?)', @message.recipient_id, @message.recipient_id)`

Both your user and recipient ids are using the recipient id. It should be

`@messages = Message.all.where('user_id IN (?) AND recipient_id IN (?)', @message.user_id, @message.recipient_id)`

You can also do:

`current_user.messages.where(recipient_id: @recipient.id)`

or

`@recipient.messages.where(user_id: @user.id)`

EDIT:

To get both directions, you can try this: (Untested)

`@messages = Message.all.where('user_id IN (?) AND recipient_id IN (?)', [@message.user_id, @message.recipient_id], [@message.user_id, @message.recipient_id])`

`IN`accepts arrays, so you can just pass in both ids for the user and both for the recipient.

Comment: This just shows me `User A`'s messages if they were the `@message.recipient` or `user` but I want to also show the current users messages sent to `User A`.

Comment: @JohnHuntington - Updated comment.